java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task; local class incompatible
I'm building an ETL for fetching data from an API, transforming it and uploading it in mongodb.
I use pyspark to distribute this process and I'm trying to use airflow to automate it.
However, I’ve hit a roadblock. After setting up Spark, Airflow and everything else, my Spark job is finally executing—but with an error :)
[2024-09-22, 13:13:46 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - Driver stacktrace:
[2024-09-22, 13:13:46 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/09/22 13:13:46 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 6.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 19) on 172.21.0.6, executor 0: java.io.InvalidClassException (org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -6188971942555435033, local class serialVersionUID = 553100815431272095) [duplicate 19]
[2024-09-22, 13:13:46 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/09/22 13:13:46 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 20) on 172.21.0.9, executor 1: java.io.InvalidClassException (org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -6188971942555435033, local class serialVersionUID = 553100815431272095) [duplicate 20]
[2024-09-22, 13:13:46 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/09/22 13:13:46 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
[2024-09-22, 13:13:47 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/09/22 13:13:46 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: foreach at /opt/***/AstroMRS/movies.py:25, took 3.357094 s
[2024-09-22, 13:13:47 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2024-09-22, 13:13:47 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - File "/opt/***/AstroMRS/movies.py", line 36, in <module>
[2024-09-22, 13:13:47 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - etl('/movie/popular', 500, 'movies_collection')
[2024-09-22, 13:13:47 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - File "/opt/***/AstroMRS/movies.py", line 25, in etl
[2024-09-22, 13:13:47 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - rdd.foreach(lambda page:
[2024-09-22, 13:13:47 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[2024-09-22, 13:13:47 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1766, in foreach
[2024-09-22, 13:13:47 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2316, in count
[2024-09-22, 13:13:47 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2291, in sum
[2024-09-22, 13:13:47 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2044, in fold
[2024-09-22, 13:13:47 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1833, in collect
[2024-09-22, 13:13:47 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
[2024-09-22, 13:13:47 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 179, in deco
[2024-09-22, 13:13:47 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
[2024-09-22, 13:13:47 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
[2024-09-22, 13:13:47 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 16) (172.21.0.9 executor 1): java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -6188971942555435033, local class serialVersionUID = 553100815431272095

this is how I made my docker-compose:
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  env_file:
    - airflow.env
  volumes:
    - .:/opt/airflow/AstroMRS
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    - postgres
  networks:
    - movie-net

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - movie-net

  spark-master:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.5.1
    command: bash -c "pip install pymongo requests && bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master"
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    environment:
      PYTHONPATH: '/opt/bitnami/spark'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/opt/bitnami/spark/src
    networks:
      - movie-net

  spark-worker-1:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.5.1
    command: bash -c "pip install pymongo requests && bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077"
    environment: 
      SPARK_MASTER_URL: spark://spark-master:7077
      SPARK_MODE: worker
      SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2 
      SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 2G
      PYTHONPATH: '/opt/bitnami/spark'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/opt/bitnami/spark/src
    depends_on: 
      - spark-master
    networks:
      - movie-net

  spark-worker-2:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.5.1
    command: bash -c "pip install pymongo requests && bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077"
    environment: 
      SPARK_MASTER_URL: spark://spark-master:7077
      SPARK_MODE: worker
      SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2 
      SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 2G
      PYTHONPATH: '/opt/bitnami/spark'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/opt/bitnami/spark/src
    depends_on: 
      - spark-master
    networks:
      - movie-net

  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.0
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - movie-net
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 5s
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - airflow-init

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    depends_on: 
      - airflow-init

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: bash -c "airflow db migrate && airflow users create \
      --username $${AIRFLOW_ADMIN_USERNAME} \
      --firstname $${AIRFLOW_ADMIN_FIRSTNAME} \
      --lastname $${AIRFLOW_ADMIN_LASTNAME} \
      --role $${AIRFLOW_ADMIN_ROLE} \
      --email $${AIRFLOW_ADMIN_EMAIL} \
      --password $${AIRFLOW_ADMIN_PASSWORD}"
    depends_on:
      - postgres

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:

networks:
  movie-net:

and here is my movies.py script:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

from src.fetch_movies import fetch_movies 
from src.transform_movies import validation_aka_transformation
from src.store_movies import save_movies_mongo

load_dotenv()
api_url = os.getenv('API_URL')
authorization_key = os.getenv('AUTHORIZATION_KEY')

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://spark-master:7077").appName("Movies Pipeline").getOrCreate()


def etl(endpoint, total_pages=None, filename=None):
    if endpoint == '/movie/latest':
        movies = fetch_movies(api_url, authorization_key, endpoint)
        transformed_movies = validation_aka_transformation(movies)
        save_movies_mongo(transformed_movies, 'movies_collection')
    else:
        pages = list(range(1, total_pages + 1))
        rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(pages, len(pages))

        rdd.foreach(lambda page: 
            save_movies_mongo(
                validation_aka_transformation(
                    fetch_movies(api_url, authorization_key, endpoint, page)
                ),
                filename
            )
        )
    print(f"ETL process completed for {endpoint}")


etl('/movie/popular', 500, 'movies_collection')
etl('/movie/top_rated', 500, 'movies_collection')
etl('/movie/latest')

The routes and everything are correct, I just don't know how to handle this obstacle.
I would very appreciate any help!
I checked the version of spark on all spark workers and spark master and they are marched.
I run the spark job outside airflow and it worked fine!

Are you running Spark 4? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-44120

@mazaneicha No, I run spark 3.5.1 in docker containers

That was my point, kind of-- python 3.12 support is only available in Spark 4 :)  Can you downgrade your python to 3.11 (supported since Spark 3.4)?

@mazaneicha I downgraded python to 3.11 and I still get the same errors :/
